# How to find the average of a noisy graph in order to get FWHM?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am considered as a very beginner to MATLAB.
I need to find a FWHM of some graphs which quite noisy and not consistence at the peak.
here below is my basic code, with the help of some codes from stackoverflow users.

```
    DD11=dicomrt_read3ddose(1,'waterphantom50x1mm15x1cmslabs500Mill_2.5cmFS_20cmx20cmDE.3ddose');
%plot first function
a=squeeze(DD11(100,:,55));
figure;
plot(a);
hold on;
%find half of maximum value
max(a);
halfAmax=0.5*(max(a));
%plot straight line across the first function
x2=[1:1:200];
LineValue=halfAmax;
plot(x2,LineValue);


%Find the starting indices of those segments of consecutive points that exceed LineValue
idx = find(diff(a >= LineValue))
hold on;
x3 = x2(idx) + (LineValue - a(idx)) .* (x2(idx+1) - x2(idx)) ./ (a(idx+1) - a(idx))
plot(x3, LineValue, 'go', [x2(1) x2(end)], LineValue*[1 1], 'k:');

%distance of the two points
fwhmwidth=[x3(end)-x3(1)].*0.1

hold on;

%plot first function
b=squeeze(DD11(100,:,7));
plot(b);
hold on;
%find half of maximum value
max(b);
halfAmax=0.5*(max(b));
%plot straight line across the first function
x2=[1:1:200];
LineValue=halfAmax;
plot(x2,LineValue);


%Find the starting indices of those segments of consecutive points that exceed LineValue
idx = find(diff(b >= LineValue))
hold on;
x3 = x2(idx) + (LineValue - b(idx)) .* (x2(idx+1) - x2(idx)) ./ (b(idx+1) - b(idx))
plot(x3, LineValue, 'go', [x2(1) x2(end)], LineValue*[1 1], 'k:');

%distance of the two points
fwhmwidth=[x3(end)-x3(1)].*0.1
```

I am hoping that;
(1) I could find the average value for those peak since they are noisy
(2) I could get a better explanation on the code which I have above like below;

```
    %Find the starting indices of those segments of consecutive points that exceed LineValue
    idx = find(diff(b >= LineValue))
    hold on;
    x3 = x2(idx) + (LineValue - b(idx)) .* (x2(idx+1) - x2(idx)) ./ (b(idx+1) - b(idx))
    plot(x3, LineValue, 'go', [x2(1) x2(end)], LineValue*[1 1], 'k:');
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to (2):

`%Find the starting...` is a commentary. In Matlab, they start by `%`.

`idx = find(diff(b >= LineValue))` locates all nonzero elements of array `diff(b >= LineValue)`, and returns the linear indices of those elements in vector `idx`. In this case, it will only return the first nonzero element. Check [Find](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/find.html)

`hold on` refers to the plot. You have already a plot and by using `hold on` you will be to add further curves to the same plot.

`x3 = x2(idx) + (LineValue - a(idx)) .* (x2(idx+1) - x2(idx)) ./` is performing operations with numbers and with matrices.  `c = a .* b` multiplies arrays `a` and `b` element-by-element and returns the result in `c`. Inputs a and b must have the same size unless one is a scalar. You can check that out in the Matlab Help  by clicking <kbd>F1</kbd>.

`plot(x3, LineValue, 'go', [x2(1) x2(end)], LineValue*[1 1], 'k:')` plots 2 different curves. The first term contains the x-axis values, the second the y-axis values and the third gives the information about the LineStyle, Color and Marker. In that case `'go'` = green circles and `'k:'` = black dots. Have a look in [Matlab's plot documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#btzpm1x) for much more info.

Hope that helps